# Decreasing an int from 10 to 0 every second in Java

Tags: java, timer, libgdx, int

I define an

```
int x = 10;
```

Now I want `x` to decrease **every second** until its 0:

```
if (Obstacle.activeItem == true) {
        game.font.draw(game.batch, "Item active for: " + x, 100, 680);
}
```

How can I do that?

I've seen people do similar things using the `Class Timer`, but I don't know how it should look like for this case.

I tried

```
int x = 10;
ScheduledExecutorService execService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

And then

```
if (Obstacle.activeItem == true) {
            game.font.draw(game.batch, "Item active for: " + x, 100, 680);
}
execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        x--;
    }
}, 0L, 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But that doesn't work as I want it to.

Comment: `Obstacle.activeItem = true` this is not how you do comparison in Java. This is assignment. You want `Obstacle.activeItem == true`, or (even better) just `if (Obstacle.activeItem)`

Comment: 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS

Comment: There is **no substitute** for [reading the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). It will tell you what the parameters are.

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 The documentation tells you it will keep running. "Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor". So then your question should be "how do I cancel an executor service?". And if you google that, you'll probably arrive at your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged your question with libGdx so I think you work with libgdx.
Instead of creating a extra ExecutorService why you don't use the `update(float delta)` method to decrease your timer?

```
private float timer = 10;
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    timer -= delta;

    if (Obstacle.activeItem == true) {
        font.draw(batch, "Item active for: " + (int)timer, 100, 680);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of how you can implement a Timer type functionality using Executors

```
public class Main {
    static int x = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService execService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            System.out.println(x);
            x--;
            if (x == 0)
                execService.shutdownNow();
        }, 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //initial delay, period, time unit
    }
}
```

It is highly recommended that you read up on Executors. Consider this as a hint and implement it in your use case accordingly.

Comment: Also, the int should be either volatile or `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @Michael agreed. But just wanted to give him a hint. He will learn about this when he'll run into volatile related issues ;)

Answer (score 0):

if that is libGdx i have some working sphagetti code for you:

```
int reducedInt = 10;
bool isReduce = false;
float timer = 1f;
```

in Render

```
timer -= delta;


if(timer<=0){

isReduce = true;
timer = 1;

}
if(isReduce){

reducedInt--;
isReduce = false;

}
```

This is classic LibGDX sphagetti timer code. Since you have tagged it as LibGDX.